# Using custom font in PDF graphics in R

Tags: r, fonts, postscript

What I need to do is provide EPS/PDFs of graphs with the in-house-font type called 'VIC' (I have the in-house font type as .otf and .ttf).

This is what I have been doing...

Adding the font:

```
library("sysfonts")
font.paths('my font path\\')
font.add(family = "VIC", 
         regular = "VIC-Regular.ttf", 
         bold = "VIC-Bold.ttf", 
         italic = "VIC-Italic.ttf", 
         bolditalic = "VIC-BoldItalic.ttf")
```

With this, I can use the fonts in graphics in R:

```
x <- rnorm(1000,1,5)
y <-  rnorm(1000,5,20)
plot(x,y, col=1:8,las=1, pch=19, cex=1, xlab="Some label name", ylab="Some label name")
```

The graph looks great, with the VIC font type on the labels and the axes, perfect!

However, when I try to export a PDF doing:

```
pdf("H:\\test.pdf", family="VIC")
plot(x,y,  xlab="Some label name", ylab="Some label name")
dev.off()
```

I get the error messages:

```
Error in pdf("H:\\test.pdf", family = "VIC") : 
  unknown family 'VIC'
```

Running:

```
pdf("H:\\test.pdf")
par(family = "VIC")
plot(x,y,  xlab="Some label name", ylab="Some label name")
dev.off()
```

gives a more informative error:

```
font family 'VIC' not found in PostScript font database
```

How do I add my font to the PostScript font database? Googling this results in a link to the package 'extrafont'. Doing

```
library(extrafont)
extrafont::ttf_import(paths = "my font path\\", 
                      recursive = TRUE, 
                      pattern = NULL)
```

seems to add the VIC font to the registry:

```
> loadfonts(device="postscript")
Registering font with R using postscriptFonts(): VIC
Registering font with R using postscriptFonts(): VIC ExtraLight
No regular (non-bold, non-italic) version of VIC ExtraLight Italic. Skipping setup for this font.
Registering font with R using postscriptFonts(): VIC Light
No regular (non-bold, non-italic) version of VIC Light Italic. Skipping setup for this font.
Registering font with R using postscriptFonts(): VIC Medium
No regular (non-bold, non-italic) version of VIC Medium Italic. Skipping setup for this font.
Registering font with R using postscriptFonts(): VIC SemiBold
No regular (non-bold, non-italic) version of VIC SemiBold Italic. Skipping setup for this font.
```

However, I still get:

```
> pdf("H:\\PDF_VIC_19_4_2.pdf", family="VIC")
Error in pdf("H:\\PDF_VIC_19_4_2.pdf", family = "VIC") : 
  unknown family 'VIC'
```

Comment: Have you check `extrafont`? http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html

Comment: Hi Adam, please check the 2nd halve of my post.

Comment: Did you try ```loadfonts()``` instead of ```loadfonts(device="postscript")``` which register the fonts to PDF?